# How to create/edit/update/delete collection that created from json object on Laravel

Tags: json, laravel

I have small laravel project working on collection. I have string data in json format store in customdata column. Below is value in table.

```
someid   somedata   customdata
1          aaa       [{"id": 1,"name":"new name","price": 20},{"id": 2,"name":"new name","price": 10}]
```

I can get data from that column and able to do some query. Let say as below dummy.

```php
$result = '[{"id": 1,"name":"new name","price": 20},{"id": 2,"name":"new name","price": 10}]';

$collection = collect(json_decode($result, true));

return $collection->where('id', 1)->first();
```

Result look like below that work as need.

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "new name",
    price: 20
}
```

But I do not know how to add new/update/delete from collection. For example if I add more data(id=3) then it would be.

```
$result = '[
    {"id": 1,"name":"new name","price": 20},
    {"id": 2,"name":"new name","price": 10},
    {"id": 3,"name":"new name","price": 15},
]';
```

It simply for model but I do not know for raw collection. Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the Collection class has a lot of useful methods to play with. You can check the [full list in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/collection).

## Adding an element to the collection

To add an element to your collection, you can use the [`push()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-push) method. From the docs:

> The push method appends an item to the end of the collection:
>
> ```
> $collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4]);
>
> $collection->push(5);
>
> $collection->all();
>
> // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> ```

In your case:

```
// your actual collection
$result = /** here you get your json */;
$collection = collect(json_decode($result, true));
// the new element
$new = ['id' => 23, 'name' => 'the latest one!', 'price' => 1200];
//adding it to the collection
$collection->push($new);
```

---

## Updating an element of the collection

To do this you have several paths.. the one that comes to my head is to generate a new collection mapping the new values in the element that matchs your condition. [From the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/collections#method-map):

> The map method iterates through the collection and passes each value
>   to the given callback. The callback is free to modify the item and
>   return it, thus forming a new collection of modified items:
>
> ```
> $collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
>
> $multiplied = $collection->map(function ($item, $key) {
>     return $item * 2;
> });
>
> $multiplied->all();
>
> // [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
> ```

So in your case:

```
$result = /** here you get your json */;
$collection = collect(json_decode($result, true));

// parameters to search and update
$id = 1 // the element id to find
$data = ['the', 'data', 'to', 'update'];

// updating the collection
$collection = $collection->map(function ($element) use ($id, $data) {
    if ($element['id'])
        $element = $data; // here goes your update logic

    return $element;
});
```

---

## Deleting element of collection

To delete element of collection you can use the [`pull()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pull) method. From the docs:

> he pull method removes and returns an item from the collection by its
>   key:
>
> ```
> $collection = collect(['product_id' => 'prod-100', 'name' => 'Desk']);
>
> $collection->pull('name');
>
> // 'Desk'
>
> $collection->all();
>
> // ['product_id' => 'prod-100']
> ```

So to remove the element of the array, we will locate the element first with the [`search()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-search) that return the key of the element to be removed, and then we use the previous mentioned method: `pull()`

```
$result = /** here you get your json */;
$collection = collect(json_decode($result, true));

// element to be deleted
$id = 1;

$key = $collection->search(function($element) use ($id) {
    return $element['id'] == $id;
});

$collection->pull($key);
```

Comment: Dear Dear HCK, So appreciated.

Comment: One more, In this case. How to remove object at id = 1 , [
{
id: 1,
name: "one",
price: 20
},
{
id: 2,
name: "two",
price: 10
},
{
id: 3,
name: "three",
price: 30
}
]

Comment: @joenpcnpcsolution sure, I forgot to add the code to actually remove the element from the collection. I've updated the answer. Have a good day.

Comment: Dear Dear HCK, So smart solution and thank you very much.

Comment: @joenpcnpcsolution it's all in the documentation my friend. Navigate through it and you will find the answers that you need.